# In NodeJS, is there a way to force a promise to resolve synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js

*I know, I know - you shouldn't do this. This is a circumstance where a refactor is out of scope and not practical or possible within the space of time that I have.*

I am making a change in some existing legacy code that relies on a block that is synchronous.

The new code depends on the resolution of a Promise but it's not practical for me to manually trace back all calls and convert them to async.

The code is not performance critical and runs once on application start, is there some way for me to wait for the promise to resolve synchronously?

Something silly like this:

```js
const si = require('systeminformation')

async function getPhysicalCores() {
  const cpu = await si.cpu()
  return cpu.physicalCores
}

function main() {
  let result = undefined
  foo().then((cores) => { result = cores })
  while (result === undefined) continue
  return result
}

main()
```

One possible approach is to use `execSync`

```js
function getPhysicalCores() {
  const result = child_process
    .execSync(`node -e "console.log((await require('systeminformation').cpus()).physicalCores)`;
  return parseInt(result, 10)
}
```

Comment: In a nutshell: no.

Comment: The only time you need to refactor a ton of code is when the function in question is at the end of a deeply nested call chain, which must `return` some value synchronously back up the call chain, and each function in the call chain uses the value directly. Or the function gets called from a ton of different places. Otherwise, some local refactoring is often all that’s needed.

Comment: That is exactly the case for me. I have a deeply nested function that used to return a synchronous value but now must return a promise. There are lots of entry points and dynamic requires above it and all the tests use `jest.Mock` extensively so they are basically useless. While a refactor would be ideal - the potential that I miss something is high.

Comment: You don't need to do a lot of refactor. All you need to do is add the keyword `async` in front of all related functions. And then add the `await` keyword in front of function calls.

Comment: It's difficult to know where all the consumers are because the function is called using a framework that dynamically generates `require()` calls, renames the target and this happens in multiple places in an enormous project. I can trace the code back to a point but it's highly likely I will miss adding `async`/`await` to some places.

Comment: If all you need is the value of `cpus()`… that's not going to change during runtime, is it? Can't you resolve that once at the start of the application and then just return it as constant value?

Comment: Well, `os.cpus()` is synchronous, as is `os.availableParallelism()`. If you had put this detail in your question to begin with...

Answer (score 2):

> is there some way for me to wait for a promise to resolve synchronously?

No. (A `while (!done) continue;` busy-loop doesn't let other tasks run, so the promise executor code is never executed.)

> runs once on application start

Then, assuming `function main()` is your actual application entry point and you don't care about its return value, i.e.

```
function main() {
  console.log("I'm an application!");
}
main();
```

you can do

```
async function init() {
  await newAsynchronousInit();
  main();
}

init();
```

(or the equivalent `.then()` version) so the asynchronous init function can do its thing however it does, and then continue with the main function.

Comment: Unfortunately, the function in my actual case is called deep within many possible entry points (Oclif CLI) with various dynamic requires obscuring all of the possible circuits. This is made worse because it's denatured in tests through `jest.Mock()`s so I have no safety in knowing what is broken and where unless it fails at runtime for consumers

Comment: Well, good luck in your refactoring then!

Comment: And what if I put a `setTimeout(() => {...}, 100);` into the while loop?

Comment: @Laca What would `...` be there?

Comment: Nothing, or just loggings.

Comment: Then you'd have a while loop that creates new deferred tasks to be run, but they never will run because that synchronous while loop is blocking.